# "Intercept" my report card before it's too late?

Tags: word-request, verbs, phrase-request

Since I got bad scores in my final (maybe straight D's, again), I have to do that. I'm not very sure about how to say/write it idiomatically.

These are my attempts:

> I have to "hijack" my report card before it arrives at the mailbox.
>
> I have to intercept my report card before it arrives at the mailbox.

Please let me know if you know a better one! Thanks!

Comment: I would use "intercept." "Hijack" implies you want to take it and use it for something else (i.e., stealing a moving vehicle to use it in a bank robbery) versus "intercept," which simply lets us know that you want to stop the arrival of the information.

Answer (score 1):

Either one is fine, and you can use quotes or not use them with *hijack*.  *Hijack* is more conversational and informal, and *intercept* is more formal or literary.  So, it's a matter of the style you want to use.

Think about this alternative as well:

> I have to hijack my report card before it gets to the mailbox.

That is more consistently conversational than using *arrives at*.  For *gets to*, you could also use *shows up at* or *makes it to*.